# UNION ALL query error expression must have same datatype as corresponding expression when all values are fillled in select

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

This maybe be a duplicate question but I can't seem to find a solution to my UNION ALL query. I keep getting this error `ERROR at line 12: ORA-01790: expression must have same datatype as corresponding expression` for this line in my query.

`SELECT ch.channel_desc, t.calendar_year, ' ', TO_CHAR(SUM(s.amount_sold), '9,999,999,999') SALES`

But I'm not sure why as I'm passing in an empty value into the select query or do I need to use NULL instead of an empty string?

```
REM let us try UNION ALL
REM 3-groupby U 2-groupby U 1-groupby U 0-groupby
Select * from
(
SELECT ch.channel_desc, t.calendar_year, co.country_region, TO_CHAR(SUM(s.amount_sold), '9,999,999,999') SALES
FROM sh2.sales s, sh2.countries co, sh2.times t, sh2.channels ch
WHERE s.time_id=t.time_id 
 AND s.channel_id= ch.channel_id
 AND ch.channel_desc IN ('Direct Sales', 'Internet') 
 AND t.calendar_year IN ('2003') 
 AND co.country_region IN ('Europe') 
GROUP BY (ch.channel_desc, t.calendar_year, co.country_region)
UNION ALL
SELECT ch.channel_desc, t.calendar_year, ' ', TO_CHAR(SUM(s.amount_sold), '9,999,999,999') SALES
FROM sh2.sales s, sh2.countries co, sh2.times t, sh2.channels ch
WHERE s.time_id=t.time_id 
 AND s.channel_id= ch.channel_id
 AND ch.channel_desc IN ('Direct Sales', 'Internet') 
 AND t.calendar_year IN ('2003') 
 AND co.country_region IN ('Europe') 
GROUP BY (ch.channel_desc, t.calendar_year)
UNION ALL
SELECT ch.channel_desc, ' ', ' ', TO_CHAR(SUM(s.amount_sold), '9,999,999,999') SALES
FROM sh2.sales s, sh2.countries co, sh2.times t, sh2.channels ch
WHERE s.time_id=t.time_id 
 AND s.channel_id= ch.channel_id
 AND ch.channel_desc IN ('Direct Sales', 'Internet') 
 AND t.calendar_year IN ('2003') 
 AND co.country_region IN ('Europe') 
GROUP BY (ch.channel_desc)
UNION ALL
SELECT ' ', ' ', ' ', TO_CHAR(SUM(s.amount_sold), '9,999,999,999') SALES
FROM sh2.sales s, sh2.countries co, sh2.times t, sh2.channels ch
WHERE s.time_id=t.time_id 
 AND s.channel_id= ch.channel_id
 AND ch.channel_desc IN ('Direct Sales', 'Internet') 
 AND t.calendar_year IN ('2003') 
 AND co.country_region IN ('Europe') 
)
ORDER BY 1 desc, 2 desc, 3 desc;
```

Comment: Is `calendar_year` a number?  Or a string?  The column name would seem to correspond to a number.  You are comparing it to a string in your `where` clause though.  If it is a number, you'd need to select a numeric value not a space for that column.  I'd wager that you really want to use `grouping sets` rather than doing a `union all` of basically the same query with different `group by` clauses.  That's going to be way more efficient. 
 https://www.oracletutorial.com/oracle-basics/oracle-grouping-sets/

Comment: calendar_year is a NUMBER(4), so could just pass in 0 instead of an empty string?

Comment: Found a solution, instead of using an empty string I used `NULL` and the query executed

Answer (score 0):

Replaced the empty string with NULL which resolved the query expression error.

`SELECT ch.channel_desc, t.calendar_year, NULL, TO_CHAR(SUM(s.amount_sold), '9,999,999,999') SALES`